# LIghtsail Magento instance redirect to domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-lightsail

I am unable to redirect my Magento Lightsail instance to a domain and not the IP address?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If your question is what it sounds like, then you're looking for [DNS](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry).  Add an A record that points to the IP of your instance.

Comment: Hi @JosephMontanaro
I've done that too but upon typing the domain name, my website shows however it shows the IP and not the domain.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I think in that case you need to set the "base url" and "secure base url" settings in the Magento backend.  Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web.  Also just a head-up, questions specific to Magento are probably better asked over on the [Magento SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/), where people are more likely interpret your question as (and have effective answers for) a Magento question.